# If a separate JVM means separate OS process

Tags: java, hadoop

Does each map and reduce task in a separate JVM mean separate OS process for each mapper and each reducer in the hadoop context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can configure tasks to reuse JVMs, but each concurrently running one will be in a separate OS process.